# Closed-form solutions for constrained multiple linear regression

Tags: regression-coefficients, constrained-regression

Normally a multiple linear regression is unconstrained
$$y=X\beta+\epsilon$$
so that closed-form solutions in the case of data orthogonality ($X^\top X=I$) are
$$\beta=(X^\top X)^{-1} X^\top y$$
Standard errors of regression coefficients, t-ratios, confidence intervals, MSE and other moment statistics can in turn be calculated from closed-form equations.

What happens to these closed-form solutions when equality and/or inequality constraints are introduced? are their estimates still valid in some way, can they be transformed to account for the new constraints, or are there none for constrained regression? for example,
$$y=X\beta+\epsilon\qquad s.t. \enspace\sum_{n=1}^N{\beta_n} =1, \enspace\beta\geq 0$$

$$\beta=?, \enspace s.e.(\beta_n)=?$$

Comment: Generically, the polytope defined by such constraints has a complexity (measured in terms of the numbers of its vertices, edges, and so on) that increases exponentially in $N:$ that alone is enough to conclude the answer to your question is in the negative.  That won't rule out closed formulas *in very special cases,* if you would care to describe a particular problem you might be facing.

Comment: just say there are N random normal variables in the columns of $X$ and you would like the regression coefficients $\beta_n$ corresponding to each $x_n$ time series to sum to 1 by the end and be non-negative

Comment: That is, indeed, much simpler: but even so, the $N-1$-simplex described by those constraints defines $2^N$ possible sets of solutions (depending on how many of the $\beta_i$ are constrained to zero): there's no way for a closed-form solution to exist.

Comment: are the unconstrained analytical solutions $\boldsymbol\beta$ still valid/provide inference somehow, or can they be transformed to account for the added constraints that produce the constrained $\boldsymbol\beta_c$, even though we know that $\boldsymbol\beta \neq \boldsymbol\beta_c$? in that unconstrained $\boldsymbol\beta$ might have negative values for example, while $\boldsymbol\beta_c$ clearly wouldn't

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires $2^N$ separate transformations, one for each boundary element of the simplex.

Comment: the special cases you mentioned in your first comment, what would they be?

Comment: They would be cases where the constraints are so redundant that the resulting polytope is extremely simple.  One example would be a large set of linear equalities, effectively reducing the number of parameters.